# PHP function to add numbers together

Tags: php

what the PHP function to add numbers together?
Like:

```
echo function("43534");
```

The output will be: 19 (4+3+5+3+4)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or should we write your code?

Comment: `function addup($value = "43534"){ return 19; };`

Comment: I search a lot, but I can't find an answer

Comment: Do you mean that you want to avoid the built-in `+` operator? If so, why?

Comment: I'm now creating a function using For Loop

Comment: "I'm now creating a function using For Loop" - can you add into the question how those variables are stored? Integers, strings, array elements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is not internal PHP function for this. You can do this using [str_split](http://us.php.net/str_split) and [array_sum](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) methods.

```
function add($string)
{
    return array_sum(str_split($string));
}
```

And call:

```
echo add("43534");
```

Of curse you need to do some validations.

Answer (score 1):

You need a very basic algorithm for this:

1. Explode by some character
   *You may sometimes need to add numbers bigger than 9. In that case, you have to explode by some character(let's say, a '+' sign), instead of only exploding by every character.
2. Get integer value of every substring
3. Add them to the sum
4. Return the result

Here is your function:

```
<?php

function add_numbers($string){
    $result = 0;
    $num_array = explode("+", $string);

    foreach($num_array as $num_array_element){
        $result += intval($num_array_element);
    }

    return $result;
}

echo add_numbers("4+3+5+3+4"); // this prints 19

?>
```

Comment: simple `array_sum(str_split($string)` is enough from @Piotr Olaszewski answer

Comment: In case he wants an alternative or something :)

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: in general, we encourage multiple answers here (it would be nice to see an attempt from the OP, but we don't prohibit answers where such an attempt has not been supplied).